# How to perform chai assert to verify that the table is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am working on protractor using cucumber. The scenario is that data is displayed in a table, and after deleting it, I have to verify that the table is blank. Following is the structure of json:

[image]

I tried the following, but it gives error:

```
 Then('The user should be deleted', async function () {
  
   return await expect(element.all(by.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-striped']")).count()).to(0);
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expect(...).to is not a function
```

Any pointer will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is relevant to this Post. But here is my 2 cents.

`jsonPayload.json`:

```
[
  { 
    ...
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    ...
  }
]
```

For Example, if i have above JSON payload & if i need to assert that the payload is empty :

```
expect(Object.keys(jsonPayload).length).to.equal(0)
```

Try similar to this in your case & see if it works.

Ensure that your `Xpath` match is returning the array & you are are able to get the count of it.